# How do I access elements in multiple nested fragment from an activity in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a "guided tour" feature for my android application and need to dim and brighten certain elements on the current screen. I am using fragments for each screen and when I try to access elements in those fragments from the activity they are always null. I have been through countless questions and none seem to help me.

The structure of the fragments is as follows:

- I'm using a Fragment TabHost that has only two tabs.
- Each tab widget has a container fragment that I use to switch between a fragment A and a fragment B within one tab.

I'm going to start the tour from Tab one, fragment b but everytime I try to get the elements they are null even if I create a new fragment the line before let alone try to drill down into nested fragments.

I am trying to find the fragment using getSupportFragmentMangager() but since I have to get elements 3 fragments deep I end up trying to do an operation on an element that is null. I hope I am not missing something simple here. I am unsure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my problem was that the view being created by the fragment was simply not finished and therefore not displayed when I called my code to get elements from the fragment layout. I needed to wait until it was done being created and then I could find any element including elements in nested fragments. The nesting of views didn't matter.

This code fixed my problem:

```
import android.os.Handler;



//After doing replace transaction
final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
final Handler handler = new Handler();
//Wait for fragment view to be created
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        //Do stuff after 100 miliseconds
        TabHostParent_Fragment myFrag = (TabHostParent_Fragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("tabhost_frag");
        Switch auto_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.auto_switch);
        auto_switch.performClick();
    }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not store a static reference to the variables you need global access to in the Activity, then access them like `MyActivity.class.myVariable` and use `getSupportFragmentManager#replace()` to swap out the fragments dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentMangager()